# Dynamic allocate 2d array and init it (segmentation fault)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am learning C and I tried to allocate memory for a 2D array (the dimensions of the array I get them from the user),  but I get a segmentation fault after I try to init it. My code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   printf("give the dimensions!\n");
   int row,col,i,j; 
   int **myArray;

   printf("\nrows = ");
   scanf("%d", &row);
   printf("columns = ");
   scanf("%d", &col);
   myArray = malloc(row*sizeof(*myArray) + col*sizeof(**myArray));

   printf("Init the array: \n");
   for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
   {
       for (j = 0; j <col ; j++)
       {
           scanf("%d", &myArray[i][j]);
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

If I change the array as `myArray[2][2]` and omit the malloc statement it works fine..

Comment: add space to `scanf(" %d", &myArray[i][j]);` once you actually set about the business of allocating a 2D array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way for C to know how your indexing is supposed to work: there's no information that associates the number of columns (`col`) with `myArray`. When you do `myArray[i][j]` with `myArray` declared as `int * *`, C will first evalutate `myArray[i]`, i.e. read the i:th value of `myArray` as if it were an integer pointer, which it isn't in your case. It will then index `j` from that invalid value, likely generating the segmentation fault (at least causing undefined behavior).

When doing it manually like that, you have two choices:

- Make it "jagged", where each row has its own pointer to that row's elements. This is what @bgamlath suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20676397/28169).
- Do the indexing yourself, by replacing `myArray[i][i]` with `myArray[i * cols + j]`.

The latter uses less memory and (way) less memorhy allocations, which is nice. Of course the indexing can be a bit awkward.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it like this.

```
  table = malloc(row*sizeof(int *));
  for(i = 0; i<row; i++)
    table[i] = malloc(col * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: yeah, i just saw an another question here similar to mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059151/segmentation-fault-on-initializing-a-2d-array?rq=1 thx!!!

Comment: That's not a 2D array, it is a pointer-based lookup table. 2D arrays are allocated in adjacent memory. [This is how you allocate a 2D array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate dynamic arrays like this. No `malloc` necessary.

```
{ 
  printf("rows = ");
  scanf("%d", &rows);
  printf("columns = ");
  scanf("%d", &cols);

  int my_array[rows][cols];
}
```

To zero the new array:

```
  memset(my_array, 0, rows*cols*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: only since C99, and provided the input isn't too large and causes the stack to overflow

Comment: Absolutely. Anyone not working with C99 or beyond needs to stick with `malloc` and `free`. Since @Nat95 tells us he's a beginner, I am guiding him toward VLAs for two reasons: 1) notational convenience, particularly with multidimensional arrays as he is looking for, and 2) freedom from endless C beginner errors surrounding `malloc` and `free`.